# Why TensorFlow spent so many time on HtoD memcpy with Titan X?

Tags: tensorflow, caffe, memcpy

I'm experiencing running AlexNet model from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/nets) in TensorFlow for evaluating time spent on GPU by library, with the following parameters and hardware:

- 1024 images on train dataset
- 10 epochs with mini-batch sizes of 128
- using GPU GTX Titan X

I stated that the real execution time on GPU is just a fraction of the all execution time of training (the graph belows compares TensorFlow and AlexNet vs Caffe and its AlexNet implementation)

[image]
(information captured with nvidia-smi. 'Porcentagem' means percentage and 'Tempo (s)' means time (seconds))

The GPU utilization rate oscilates frenetically between 0 and 100% in training. Why that? Caffe doesn't oscilates to much beyond 40%

Also, Tensorflow spent many time doing memory copy from Host to Device, while Caffe doesn't. But why?
[image]
(tensorflow)

[image]
(caffe)